# Is there a wildcard character in python

Tags: python, string

To be more specific, it's for an "if" condition
I have a list of strings which have 5 spaces then the last character

Is there a character that can replace the last character of every string

Like:

```
if string == "     &":
     do something
```

And the condition would be true if & == any type of character

Comment: Do you mean a [wildcard character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character) of some sort?

Comment: Negative index? `test = "123A"` then `if test[-1] == "A":` ?

Comment: Yes i mean a wildcard character

Comment: Not entirely clear: Do you just want to check what the last character is some specific char, or should the entire string follow some pattern with one of several possible characters in the last (or any other) position?

Comment: Can you flesh out your example, like a sample list of strings? You say you have a list of strings either "O" or "A". Well, in that example those are single character strings and the idea of "last character" doesn't make sense.

Comment: The entire string should follow a pattern, where the last character could by everything. That's why i want to use a wildcard character.

Comment: The example i gave were bad, just image a string wich has 5 space (they where deleted by stackoverflow) than the last character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the last character by slicing, e.g. -1 is the last one:

```
lst = ['&', 'A', 'B', 'C']

s = 'some random string which ends on &'

if s[-1] in lst:
        print('hurray!')

#hurray!
```

Alternatively you can also use `.endswith()` if its only a few entries:

```
s = 'some random string which ends on &'

if s.endswith('&') or s.endswith('A'):
        print('hurray!')

#hurray!
```

Since you also asked how to replace the last character, this can be done like this:

```
s = s[:-1] + '!'
#Out[72]: 'some random string which ends on !'
```

As per you comment, here is a wildcard solution:

```
import re
s = r'    &'
pattern = r'    .{1}$'
if re.search(pattern, s):
        print('hurray!')
#hurray!
```

Comment: Since the last character can be any letter in uppercase or lowercase, or any figure. The wildcard character is what i'm searching for. To avoid creating a list for every possibility

Comment: @NicolasMorvanBenot taht seems to be different than what you wrote in your question. But I added the solution with wildcard at the end of my answer. The `.` is the wildcard, the `{1}` means only 1 wildcard character, the `$` means the wildcard has to be the last character of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if string[-1] == 'A' or string[-1] == '1':
    do something
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use a regular expression along with `re.search`, for example:

```py
vals = ["validA", "valid1", "invalid"]
for val in vals:
    if re.search(r'[A1]$', val):
        print(val + ": MATCH")
```

This prints:

```
validA: MATCH
valid1: MATCH
```

Comment: Why not add the spaces to the pattern? I think they are important, not just "the last char should be XYZ" (although that part is not really clear from the question)

Comment: @tobias_k Based on my reading of the question, the spaces in the OP's sample string are in fact just placeholders for any characters.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're looking for the [.endswith()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_endswith.asp) function? For example:

```
if "waffles".endswith("s"):
    ...
```